# Attribute error in 'file' and 'File' object in hdf5 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, hdf5, h5py

I have created a `hdf5` file using `file = open()` command. In this case, I can write and read the file. But it is giving me attribute error when I am trying `file.keys()`. The error is `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'keys'`.

Then I have created a new `hdf5` file using `file = h5py.File()` command. In this case, I can read and use command `file.keys()` without any error. But I can not write in the file. The error is  `AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'write'`.

What are the reasons behind these error? Is there any difference between `'file'` object and `'File'` object?

Answer (score 1):

`open()` returns an object of type `file`, that is the Python built in standard type to represent a file. This has quite a simple / low level interface and you would use it if you were reading a text file or parsing the content (be that text or binary) yourself. You can read the docs on the methods the `file` type has here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

`h5py.File()` returns a different type of object that has additional functionality to handle the hdf5 format and provides it's own different API e.g. the `keys()` method you mention.

When opening a `h5py.File()` you must specify how you want to open it e.g. `r+` for read/write mode. Someone with a better understanding of the h5py library may be able to give a better explanation for this but the reason you can not call `write()` on the `h5py.File()` object is because it does not have a `write` method as suggested by the error message.

Checkout the API docs for h5py, it provides different methods for writing different data to the file - http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html